# Show that username is available even when already exists

Tags: php, mysql

Right now my it shows that the username is available even when the name already exists in my database.

php

```
session_start();
$conne=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","","my_db");

$name = $_POST['name'];

$check_if_exists="SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = '$name'";
$count = mysql_num_rows($check_if_exists);
if($count != 0) { 

 $_SESSION['msg']="The name already exists. Please try another name";

} else {

$sql="INSERT INTO names(name) values('$name')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   $_SESSION['msg']="The name was inserted successfully";
  }
}

header("location:form.php");
```

Somehow it shows that the name is available and it will insert en give the message that the action was succesfull

html

```
<div class="msg"> 
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg]);
}
?>
</div>

<form action="check_insert.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required> 
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Voeg domein toe!">

</form>
```

Comment: Maybe you are wrong on using mysql instead of mysqli

Comment: I can suggest you to fetch the result first, instead of counting them. if It had more than 0 items, it's successful and vice versa. It will effect your performance too

Comment: Why not just use the persons email address instead of a username - one less thing for them to forget

Comment: Please Please Please and Pretty please look up SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issues in your code:

```
$check_if_exists="SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = '$name'";
$count = mysqli_num_rows($check_if_exists);
```

This should be like that (**you miss the mysqli_query function**):

```
$check_if_exists="SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($check_if_exists);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count != 0) { 
//your code
}
```

And this line:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
    $_SESSION['msg']="The name was inserted successfully";
}
```

Should be like that (**you declared connection variable as $conne not $conn**):

```
if ($conne->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
    $_SESSION['msg']="The name was inserted successfully";
}
```

**Side Note:**

I don't think, if you not use `name="submit"` in button it will work or not.

Comment: I suppose you work for talk-talk and do not mind SQL injection

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it for me, understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @Kevin: as ed heal said, u need some protection for SQL injection. read how to protect ....

Comment: @devpro I got it in my code, I only try to post my code here as short als possible. Will post it in my code next time I have a question. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: @EdHeal: brother OP provided the answer as u ask, thank you for reminding..

Answer (score 1):

In your code you just called `mysqli_num_rows` before calling `mysqli_query`. `mysqli_num_rows` counts the number of rows on a result set which is returned by mysqli_query and not on the query (text) itself.